# Can an item frame that opens a door close it immediately after?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I wanted to know how to get an item frame to activate redstone so I can have it open a secret passage. I then found [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310916).  At the bottom there is a link for a video (It was made by "SethBling") and I figured out how to open doors with the item frame. So now I am wondering after if there is a way to reset the item frame and therefor have it close the door behind me after a time limit (similar to a button).

Comment: What have you tried to reset the system so far?

Comment: Nothing, I can't get on rn but I wanted to experiment with the answers I got

Comment: Fair enough, I’m loading it up to see what I can do before bed lol

Comment: lol, thank you very much, you have helped a lot.

Comment: Cleaned up my screenshot and explained the delays to help clarify my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got was about the equivalent timing of a button press. You'll need the following to accomplish it:

- Item Frame
- Redstone Dust
- Redstone Observer
- Redstone Comparator
- Redstone Repeater

The idea I ran with, was to utilize the locking feature of the repeater to delay the de-activation of the primary observer. The circuit looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the layout.]

Additional delay can be added by adding a secondary lock after the first set. The truly important note here is with regards to the redstone repeaters. The delay sequence is important:

1. The repeater sending the signal to the door.

   - This should have a delay of 2 ticks.
2. The repeater receiving the primary observer signal.

   - This should have a delay of 3 ticks.
3. The repeater pointed at repeater 2.

   - This should have a delay of 4 ticks.

You can adjust the delay of the repeaters by triggering the "use" functionality when aiming at them.

Comment: Also, this doesn’t reset the orientation of the item in the frame, not sure that’s possible.

Comment: Resetting the orientation of the item in the item frame is currently impossible to do without the player either cycling through all the stages manually, or removing and replacing the item. So no, not possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the state of an item frame would only be possible through commands (and even then not quite easy). What you can do in regular survival without cheats is:

- require a certain number of rotations, independent from initial position (observer watching redstone dust from a comparator, producing a pulse on every change), pass that to a counter.
- activate a delay circuit that will close the door after a certain period (allowing you to reset the frame manually - even if you leave it in the correct position and come back later, you'll need to reset it before setting it right)
- activate a dispenser with some kind of projectiles (like snowballs) to shoot the item frame, in result ejecting the item from it and making it drop to the floor (where you may try to collect it with hoppers, or just leave it to despawn.)

Answer (score 0):

This should have a delay of 4 ticks.
You can adjust the delay of the repeaters by triggering the "use" functionality when aiming at them.